# Who is this monument near Huesca for?

Tags: identification, spain, monument

Roadside monument about 1.1 KM east of [Huesca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huesca).
Location (within ten meters): [42°8'27.90"N, 0°22'23.16"W](https://earth.google.com/web/@42.14097209,-0.37302487,466.51418497a,0d,60y,-24.2217h,89.9999t,0.0001r/data=IhoKFjVpSlYxQjhnc2FCbFZRTWd1SHphX3cQAg).

According to Wiktionary, “requetés” could mean soldiers fighting for Carlos 1833–1840 or soldiers fighting for Franco 1936 to 1939.  I don't know which, but I'm guessing the latter, as this thing doesn't appear to be 150 years old.

Anyone know for certain?

[image: Roadside monument about 1.1 KM east of Huesca]

The inscription reads (with spelling corrections):

> Señor, tened piedad de los requetés del tercio de Doña María de las nieves que aquí murieron por vuestra santa causa y la de España. R.I.P.

Translation:

> Lord, have mercy on the [recruits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requet%C3%A9s) of the [Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tercio) of Doña María de las Nieves who died here for your holy cause and that of Spain. R.I.P.

Comment: http://www.requetes.com/nieves.html ?

Comment: Thanks!  I made the assumption that it referred to "Our Lady of the Snows" and was puzzled by the omission of "Santa."  I missed "tercio" which should have helped me avoid the mistake.

Comment: So do we consider this question answered?

Comment: @CarlosMartin Seems the question is: does anyone feel apt enough to follow & check & expand the helpful bread crumb comment above to a proper answer? I've heard we should have a box for that, ready  just here on this page?

Comment: I was hinting at that.  I would have done it myself eventually but wanted to let Tomás or someone else claim the credit.

Answer (score 1):

They were volunteers (very young according to the [cited Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requet%C3%A9s)) fighting in the Carlist Wars.  Details in the comments and edited into the question.  Also,

- https://requetespuntocom.blogspot.com/2019/01/los-testimonios-de-requetes-destilan-en.html
- http://www.requetes.com/nieves.html

Comment: Hm. A bit terse. So, when did they die, (how/why/engagement, and when was this erected)? (Technically, 'it is answered', but still…)

Comment: I'd be happy to accept a more complete answer from someone with more knowledge than I got from the comments.

Comment: Well, they weren't fighting for King Carlos, because Carlos María Isidro de Borbón had died in 1855 and this monument is for the casualties they suffered during 1936 and 1937. The king they wanted to nominate was Alfonso de Borbón y Austria-Este (Alfonso Carlos I).

Comment: Edited.  But again, it would be great to have an answer from someone who really knows what was going on.  I can read Spanish, but I'm too lazy to translate the cited pages.